# Includes and grouping in sequelize in nested structure

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I am trying to simplify my response structure by grouping based on keys in `orderMicrobial` and also want to do a sum on quantity based on the grouping. I would like to have to have the following response:

#### Expected

```
   {
        "pendingInfo": [
            {
                "testTypeID": "1",
                "testType": "Breathing Air",
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "testTypeID": "2",
                "testType": "Manufacturing",
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "testTypeID": "3",
                "testType": "Microbial w/o spares",
                "quantity": 3
            },
            {
                "testTypeID": "3",
                "testType": "Microbial sealed pack",
                "quantity": 5
             },
             {
                "testTypeID": "3",
                "testType": "Microbial w/ spares",
                "quantity": 2
             },
         ]
    }
```

#### Currently

```
{
    "pendingInfo": [
        {
            "testTypeID": "1",
            "testType": "Breathing Air",
            "orders": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "orderMicrobial": null
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "orderMicrobial": null
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "orderMicrobial": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "testTypeID": "2",
            "testType": "Manufacturing",
            "orders": [
                {
                    "quantity": 5,
                    "orderMicrobial": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "testTypeID": "3",
            "testType": "Microbial",
            "orders": [
                {
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "orderMicrobial": {
                        "hasSealedPlatePacks": null,
                        "hasSpares": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "orderMicrobial": {
                        "hasSealedPlatePacks": true,
                        "hasSpares": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "orderMicrobial": {
                        "hasSealedPlatePacks": true,
                        "hasSpares": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "orderMicrobial": {
                        "hasSealedPlatePacks": null,
                        "hasSpares": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Query

```
const categorySummary = await TestType.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: Order,
      as: 'orders',
      include: [{
        model: OrderMicrobial,
        attributes: ['hasSealedPlatePacks', 'hasSpares']
      }],
      attributes: ['quantity']
    }],
    attributes: [
      ['testtypeID', 'testTypeID'],
      ['testtypeName', 'testType']
    ]
```

Comment: I would better use the application code to achieve this than writing that complex query can slow down the query performance. If the query doesn't return huge data, application-level implementation is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add nested attributes to a top level.

```js
await TestType.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Order,
    as: 'orders',
    include: [{
      model: OrderMicrobial,
      attributes: []  // remove from nested object
    }],
    attributes: []  // remove from nested object
  }],
  attributes: [
    ['testtypeID', 'testTypeID'],
    [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('testtypeName')), 'testType'],
    [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('orders.quantity')), 'quantity'],
    [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('orders.orderMicrobial.hasSealedPlatePacks')), 'hasSealedPlatePacks'],
    [Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('orders.orderMicrobial.hasSpares')), 'hasSpares'],
  ],
  group: [
    Sequelize.col('testtypes.testtypeID'),  // adjust this to your test type table name if this is not correct
    Sequelize.fn('COALESCE', Sequelize.col('orders.orderMicrobial.hasSealedPlatePacks'), -1),
    Sequelize.fn('COALESCE', Sequelize.col('orders.orderMicrobial.hasSpares'), -1)
  ],
  raw: true   // make sure to add this
})
```

This will return the `quantity` in string. If you need integer, try changing the `quantity` line to

```
[Sequelize.literal('CAST(SUM(`orders`.`quantity`) AS UNSIGNED)'), 'quantity']
```

Comment: this is way close to what I have been trying to achieve. The only part that feels tricky to me is to split only the microbial into 3 different objects based on hasSpares/hasSealedPlatePacks. Also quantity needs to be sum under each category including microbial.

Comment: I updated my answer. could you try again?

Comment: So, the updated answer does the sum for breathing air and manufacturing, but not for microbial. In fact, the microbial needs to be formed into 3 objects according to the expected response structure in the question.

Comment: 3 objects which is grouped by the `hasSealedPlatePacks`, `hasSpares` true/false combo, right?  I added those columns in `group`. Could you make sure that is added in `GROUP BY` clause? Please show the generated query.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed that if `hasSealedPlatePacks: true` then `hasSpares: false`. Although both can be null, if its a pack without spares and not a sealed pack.

Comment: SELECT `testtype`.`testtypeID`, `testtype`.`testtypeID` AS `testTypeID`, `testtype`.`testtypeName` AS `testType`, SUM(`orders`.`quantity`) AS `quantity` FROM `testtype` AS `testtype` LEFT OUTER JOIN `order` AS `orders` ON `testtype`.`testtypeID` = `orders`.`testtypeID` LEFT OUTER JOIN `orderMicrobial` AS `orders->orderMicrobial` ON `orders`.`orderID` = `orders->orderMicrobial`.`orderID` GROUP BY `testtype`.`testtypeID`, `orders->orderMicrobial`.`hasSealedPlatePacks`, `orders->orderMicrobial`.`hasSpares`;

Comment: I updated again, please check.  the issue was the grouping the nulls, I needed to coalesce to another value to make the right grouping.  And even with the right grouping, Sequelize try to drop the some rows, so I needed to add `raw: true`.